# Is this "no machine error" a potential security flag?

Tags: virus

I posted this  in a help forum in an unobscured version and I want to know if I opened a back door to bad guys.
```
X.x.x.y.y.y.z.z homestead #vagrant 374738jdjfjdjd (homestead-7) 7373636hdhdhd

X.x.x.y.y.y.z.z apache #vagrant 374738jdjfjdjd (apache) 7373636hdhdhd
```

I ran vagrant up on a VM and received this  suspicious error.

`==> homestead-7: [vagrant-hostsupdater] Removing hosts
==> homestead-7: [vagrant-hostsupdater] No machine id, nothing removed from C:/WINDOWS/system32/drivers/etc/hosts`